# Issue with tkinter in vs code

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, tkinter

I installed all the necessary plug-ins in my vscode to interpret my python code. Whenever I run my code only the window pop ups not the text or buttons I create in it.

I was not that my Mac version needs to be up to date so I installed the latest macOS version but it didn't work. Tried changing my font size and colour also but didn't work.
Here is my code

```
import tkinter

class myGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self.main_window.title("Welcome Program")
        self.label1 = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text="Welcome to Python")
        self.label2 = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text="Welcome to Computer Science")
        self.label3 = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text="Programming is fun")

        self.label1.pack()
        self.label2.pack()
        self.label3.pack()

# Create an instance of the class
my_gui = myGUI()

# Start the Tkinter event loop
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: We can't possibly comment without seeing your code.  There are a hundred things you could have done wrong.

Comment: Does it work if you run the script from a Terminal window instead of VS Code?

Comment: No doesn't work

Comment: Try installing the Python from python.org.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `tkinter.mainloop()` with `my_gui.main_window.mainloop()` so it runs on the window attribute within the class itself.

Comment: Hi Ben,

I just wanted to drop you a quick note to say thanks for your help with my code. Your suggestion to replace "tkinter.mainloop()" with "my_gui.main_window.mainloop()" did the trick, and now my code is running smoothly. I really appreciate your assistance.

Thanks again!

Comment: @JaySiyani No problem! Please marked this as answered so others with this question can find the answer more easily in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not running in my windows 10 system neither
Doing this is running for me, you could check it.

removes:

```
tkinter.mainloop()
```

and add at the end of the class:

```
self.main_window.mainloop()
```

like this:

```
self.label1.pack()
        
self.label2.pack()

self.label3.pack()

self.main_window.mainloop() # Here
```

Comment: Hey Mate,
I tried "self.main_window.mainloop()" as you said and didn't work saying self is not "defined" but after replacing self with "mu_gui.main_window.mainloop()" it worked. Just wanted to thank you for your help.
Thanks Again!

Comment: I'm glad you've made progress!